# Unable to upload ROOT.war using tomcat manager

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat8, amazon-elb

I am using Tomcat with Apache httpd in aws environment. I am facing an issue deploying application using the manager. I can deploy it by manually by uploading the ROOT.war, and the application works fine.

The following errors I get from Tomcat and Apache:

```
SEVERE [ajp-nio-8009-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: FAIL - Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Proc
essing of multipart/form-data request failed. null]
 java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2950)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3242)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1136)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:479)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2902)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:1279)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.readMessage(AjpProcessor.java:618)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.receive(AjpProcessor.java:580)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.refillReadBuffer(AjpProcessor.java:688)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(AjpProcessor.java:1390)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:659)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
```

And from apache httpd:

```
[proxy_ajp:error] [pid xxx] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx] AH0XXXX: dialog with client x.x.x.x:xxxx failed, referer: https://hostname.com/manager/html
```

I have tried increasing connectionTimeout values in Tomcat and proxyTimeout in Apache. However, nothing helps.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing Apache's mod_reqtimeout. Check whether it is loaded:

```
$ apachectl -M
```

If it is, you might try setting `RequestReadTimeout` to a larger value. See the manual at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html.

Example (using the default values, adjust them fitting your needs):

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
    RequestReadTimeout header=20-40 body=20
</IfModule>
```

Usually this is configured in the Apache VirtualHost config.

Please bear in mind that setting values higher than the default ones could expose the server to attacks such as Slowloris.